# jquery .add() not adding html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, addition

I have an array of elements, which i wish to put into one jquery object.
jquery.add() does not seem to be adding elements into my jquery object. I have console logs showing that the things I am adding are indeed html elements, yet still they arent added in
what am i doing wrong?

my code:

```
console.log('iterating')
console.log(content)
//add the content into the jquery item, and then we can load it into the qtip
_.each(additionalContent, function(value, element, list){
console.log('adding')
console.log(value)
console.log(content.length)
content.add(value) //trying content.add($(value)) gives the same result/output
console.log(content.length)
})

console.log('asdf')
console.log(content.length)
console.log(content)
```

======================
prints the following:

```
iterating 
[p.nonVendor unselectable, selector: "", context: undefined, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
adding 
<button class type=​"button" data-loading-text=​"OK" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ font-style:​ normal;​ font-variant:​ normal;​ font-weight:​ normal;​ font-size:​ 13px;​ line-height:​ normal;​ font-family:​ arial;​ color:​ rgb(255, 255, 255)​;​ background-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 255)​;​ z-index:​ 2;​ display:​ inline;​ left:​ auto;​ top:​ auto;​ width:​ 35.77777862548828px;​ height:​ 17.777777671813965px;​">​OK​</button>​
1 
1 
adding
<button class type=​"button" data-loading-text=​"Cancel" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ font-style:​ normal;​ font-variant:​ normal;​ font-weight:​ normal;​ font-size:​ 13px;​ line-height:​ normal;​ font-family:​ arial;​ color:​ rgb(255, 255, 255)​;​ background-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 255)​;​ z-index:​ 2;​ display:​ inline;​ left:​ auto;​ top:​ auto;​ width:​ 35.77777862548828px;​ height:​ 17.777777671813965px;​">​Cancel​</button>​
1 
1 
asdf 
1 
[p.nonVendor unselectable, selector: "", context: undefined, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

Comment: What is "content"? *edit* oh I see

Comment: Where exactly are you using 'jquery.add()' to add the Elements ?

Comment: content variable is a jquery object (line 2 of code)

Comment: Have you tried `content.add($(value));` ??

Comment: yes i tried content.add($(value)) /// the output is exactly the same

Comment: Hmm well I'm still guessing here, but the next thing I'd try is `content.add($.parseHTML(value));`. Version 1.9 is picky about HTML strings.

Comment: Hm I had something similar in Node with mongoDB. I needed to first call toObject() on the mongoDB-object in order to manipulate it. Maybe it is similar with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.add() does not change the original var, so you need to assign the result back to 'content' as follows:

```
content = content.add($(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a javascript array containing both the objects in `content` and `additionalContent` the following code will work:

```
elements = [];
content.each(function(index, value) {
    elements.push(value);
});
additionalContent.each(function(index, value) {
    elements.push(value);
});
```

A couple of points:

- the first argument of your each function will be loaded with an index (similar to using a for loop: for( int index = 0; index < content.length; index++ ), the second argument is the element
- the jQuery method .add is used for handling selectors rather than collections of objects and does not behave quite in the way required for your code

The `elements` collection can then be used in an object - is this what you require?

**Edit - to concatenate the Jquery Selectors:**

as wdosanjos points out the following will work - no `.each` required:

```
content = content.add(additionalContent);
```

To add the css class sausage to all of the elements in both selectors:

```
content.add(additionalContent).addClass('sausage');
```